# segfault when attempting to access members of QGraphicsTextItem

Tags: c++, qt

I'm a bit new to c++ and am having a bit of trouble establishing why I am getting a segfault in the following code;

gamescene.h

```
#ifndef GAMESCENE_H
#define GAMESCENE_H

#include <QGraphicsScene>

class GameScene : public QGraphicsScene
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit GameScene(QObject *parent = 0);
    virtual void keyPressEvent(QKeyEvent* );
    QGraphicsTextItem* p;
    ~GameScene();
signals:

public slots:

};

#endif // GAMESCENE_H
```

gamescene.cpp

```
#include "gamescene.h"
#include "QKeyEvent"
#include "QGraphicsTextItem"
#include "QGraphicsRectItem"
#include "QDebug"
#include "QGraphicsScene"
#include "QScopedPointer"


GameScene::GameScene(QObject *parent) :
    QGraphicsScene(parent)
{
    QGraphicsTextItem* p = new QGraphicsTextItem(QString("HEEEEE"));
    p->setFlags(p->ItemIsMovable);
    p->moveBy(qreal(500),qreal(500));
    addItem(p);
}

void GameScene::keyPressEvent(QKeyEvent *event)

{
    qDebug() << (p != NULL);
    switch(event->key())
    case ( Qt::Key_W ):
    {
        qreal x, y;
        x = qreal(5);
        y = qreal(5);
        p->moveBy(x,y);
        qDebug() << "move up";

    }

}
GameScene::~GameScene() {


}
```

Its happening when my gamescene object's keyPressEvent method is called and it attempts to access anything to do with the QGraphicsTextItem pointer, p.

I'm sure its obvious, but any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You should assign the parent of QGraphicsTextItem when it is constructed.  This will mean that it gets deleted at an appropriate time.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong or misunderstanding something, but I thought that when calling addItem, the scene takes ownership of the item.

Comment: Yes, that is correct.  However I would suggest it is still good practice to use the QObject(parent) constructor (by proxy from the subclass constructor) when the intended parent is in scope at construction time.

Comment: With the QGraphicsTextItem object it doesn't appear possible to set the parent through the constructor, unless it is to be a child of another QGraphicsItem, unless I create it using the scene's addText method. Or is there something fundamental I'm missing here?

Comment: I didn't notice that.  It isn't clear to me why it takes a QGraphicsItem parent and not a QObject parent.  Bizarre.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, I know nothing about the library you are using but I suspect the error is here

```
GameScene::GameScene(QObject *parent) :
    QGraphicsScene(parent)
{
    QGraphicsTextItem* p = new QGraphicsTextItem(QString("HEEEEE"));
    p->setFlags(p->ItemIsMovable);
    p->moveBy(qreal(500),qreal(500));
    addItem(p);
}
```

should be

```
GameScene::GameScene(QObject *parent) :
    QGraphicsScene(parent)
{
    p = new QGraphicsTextItem(QString("HEEEEE"));
    p->setFlags(p->ItemIsMovable);
    p->moveBy(qreal(500),qreal(500));
    addItem(p);
}
```

Your `keyPressEvent` method tries to use a member variable called p, and it looks like you are trying to set that up in the constructor, but you aren't. All you have in your constructor is local variable also called p.

Comment: It's a good convention to always name class variables differently from normal variables by using a prefix. For instance some people say `class X { int myVariable; };`, some say `class X { int m_Variable; };`, personally I do it like this `class X { int _variable; };` although people tell me off for that. In any case it's a good idea to have a clear distinction between names of class variables and normal variables to avoid confusion.

Comment: @jahhaj: Identifiers starting with an underscore are reserved for the system (compiler and standard libraries).  You risk a difficult to debug naming conflict by using them.

Comment: I told you I get told off for this! Identifiers starting with an underscore are reserved for the compiler at file scope only. I'm not using them at file scope.